# Send an error to appengine endpoint client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In my GAE endpoint, in my user register API method, I check whether a user already exists with the given username. If a user already exists, I need to send an error to the endpoint client.

Currently I throw an [exception](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions) like below from endpoint.

```
User user = ofy().load().key(Key.create(User.class, username)).now();
if (user != null) {
    throw new BadRequestException("Username already exists");
}
```

Then in endpoint client, I catch the exception like below.

```
try {
    gaeEndpoint.registerUser(mEmail, mPassword).execute();
} catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    mErrorMessage = e.getContent();
} catch (IOException e) {
    mErrorMessage = "Failed to communicate with server. Please check your internet connection.";
}
```

When endpoint throws a BadRequestException, client gets `HttpResponseException e` and `e.getContent()` contains a json string including the error message string sent from endpoint. I need to parse json to get the actual error message sent from server.

Even though this works, I feel that there should be a better way to send an error message to the client from the endpoint. So, does anyone know a better (or a recommended) way of doing this?

Comment: Looks okay to me. Your `HttpResponseException` not only contains a content section. It should contain a statusCode, which should be much easier to handle in code than the content, because `if(statusCode == 400){Whoopsie...}` is easier to do than to parse the response and work with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing everything right.

HTTP is designed to send a response with 4xx code and meaningful content to a user. It can be HTML for a browser, JSON for an api client or anything that can provide some context to the client.

If you're worried about using exceptions, that's fine too. Of course, you can prepare a response with a manually set status code, but that doesn't change anything, it's just more code. It's also less likely that you'll create a bug when you're using exceptions in this case.